# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path designGoal.jsp does not start with a "/" character

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am writing a very simple web application using servlets and JSP, in Eclipse. The server is Tomcat v7.0. Java version is 1.8.0_60. Below is my servlet code, written in file named `DesignGoal.java`

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(
    urlPatterns = "/DesignGoal",
    initParams = {
            @WebInitParam(name="text",value=" extreme knitting " )
    }
)
public class DesignGoal extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher view = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/designGoal.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

And this is my file `designGoal.jsp`:

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    Hello!
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I run the file `DesignGoal.java`, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path designGoal.jsp does not start with a "/" character
```

Can someone please tell me why I get this error, even when the string in `getRequestDispatcher()` starts with `/`, and the path that I have added is relative to the root of the Project.

Comment: *"even when the string in `getRequestDispatcher()` starts with `/`."* - Isn't the error message telling you **not** to start `designGoal.jsp` with a `/`? Also, typically a `/` preceding a file means that said file is in the root directory. Perhaps you meant to put `./` (current directory)?

Comment: I've tried three different things: **./designGoal.jsp**, **/designGoal.jsp**, **designGoal.jsp**, but it gives the exact same error in all three cases.

Comment: @Caesar is your `designGoal.jsp` in the root directory

Comment: @Ramanlfc It is in the WebContent folder

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
RequestDispatcher view = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("designGoal.jsp");<!--dont add '/' here   --!>
view.forward(request, response);
```

}

Dont add the "/" in dispatcher

Comment: Single line comments in Java are preceded by `//`, like `// this is a comment`. While in HTML they are `<!-- comment -->`.

Comment: to get dispatcher using `ServletContext`using `/` (root directory) is necessary

Answer (score 0):

If your designGoal.jsp in the root directory WebContent

```
String nextJSP = "/searchResults.jsp";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

If it is in the WebContent/WEB-INF folder

```
String nextJSP = "/WEB-INF/searchResults.jsp";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```